# Oh-My-Zsh completion not working

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh, completion

I reinstalled my computer running macOS Sierra and also reinstalled oh-my-zsh. I copied over my old zshrc, which was working fine (and is still working fine on another computer).

However, every start of the zsh, the following output emerges, before the shell starts up:

```
    bracketed-paste-magic () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XUz
}
colors () {
        emulate -L zsh
        typeset -Ag color colour
        color=(00 none 01 bold 02 faint 22 normal 03 standout 23 no-standout 04 underline 24 no-underline 05 blink 25 no-blink 07 reverse 27 no-reverse 08 conceal 28 no-conceal 30 black 40 bg-black 31 red 41 bg-red 32 green 42 bg-green 33 yellow 43 bg-yellow 34 blue 44 bg-blue 35 magenta 45 bg-magenta 36 cyan 46 bg-cyan 37 white 47 bg-white 39 default 49 bg-default)
        local k
        for k in ${(k)color}
        do
                color[${color[$k]}]=$k
        done
        for k in ${color[(I)3?]}
        do
                color[fg-${color[$k]}]=$k
        done
        color[grey]=${color[black]}
        color[fg-grey]=${color[grey]}
        color[bg-grey]=${color[bg-black]}
        colour=(${(kv)color})
        local lc=$'\e[' rc=m
        typeset -Hg reset_color bold_color
        reset_color="$lc${color[none]}$rc"
        bold_color="$lc${color[bold]}$rc"
        typeset -AHg fg fg_bold fg_no_bold
        for k in ${(k)color[(I)fg-*]}
        do
                fg[${k#fg-}]="$lc${color[$k]}$rc"
                fg_bold[${k#fg-}]="$lc${color[bold]};${color[$k]}$rc"
                fg_no_bold[${k#fg-}]="$lc${color[normal]};${color[$k]}$rc"
        done
        typeset -AHg bg bg_bold bg_no_bold
        for k in ${(k)color[(I)bg-*]}
        do
                bg[${k#bg-}]="$lc${color[$k]}$rc"
                bg_bold[${k#bg-}]="$lc${color[bold]};${color[$k]}$rc"
                bg_no_bold[${k#bg-}]="$lc${color[normal]};${color[$k]}$rc"
        done
}
compdump () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XUz
}
compinit () {
        emulate -L zsh
        setopt extendedglob
        typeset _i_dumpfile _i_files _i_line _i_done _i_dir _i_autodump=1
        typeset _i_tag _i_file _i_addfiles _i_fail=ask _i_check=yes _i_name
        while [[ $# -gt 0 && $1 = -[dDiuC] ]]
        do
                case "$1" in
                        (-d) _i_autodump=1
                                shift
                                if [[ $# -gt 0 && "$1" != -[dfQC] ]]
                                then
                                        _i_dumpfile="$1"
                                        shift
                                fi ;;
                        (-D) _i_autodump=0
                                shift ;;
                        (-i) _i_fail=ign
                                shift ;;
                        (-u) _i_fail=use
                                shift ;;
                        (-C) _i_check=
                                shift ;;
                esac
        done
        typeset -gHA _comps _services _patcomps _postpatcomps
        typeset -gHA _compautos
        typeset -gHA _lastcomp
        if [[ -n $_i_dumpfile ]]
        then
                typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="$_i_dumpfile"
        else
                typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zcompdump"
        fi
        typeset -gHa _comp_options
        _comp_options=(bareglobqual extendedglob glob multibyte multifuncdef nullglob rcexpandparam unset NO_allexport NO_aliases NO_cshnullglob NO_cshjunkiequotes NO_errexit NO_globassign NO_globsubst NO_histsubstpattern NO_ignorebraces NO_ignoreclosebraces NO_kshglob NO_ksharrays NO_kshtypeset NO_markdirs NO_octalzeroes NO_posixbuiltins NO_shwordsplit NO_shglob NO_warncreateglobal)
        typeset -gH _comp_setup='local -A _comp_caller_options;
             _comp_caller_options=(${(kv)options[@]});
             setopt localoptions localtraps localpatterns ${_comp_options[@]};
             local IFS=$'\'\ \\t\\r\\n\\0\'';
             builtin enable -p \| \~ \( \? \* \[ \< \^ \# 2>/dev/null;
             exec </dev/null;
             trap - ZERR;
             local -a reply;
             local REPLY'
        typeset -ga compprefuncs comppostfuncs
        compprefuncs=()
        comppostfuncs=()
        : $funcstack
        compdef () {
                local opt autol type func delete eval new i ret=0 cmd svc
                local -a match mbegin mend
                emulate -L zsh
                setopt extendedglob
                if (( ! $# ))
                then
                        print -u2 "$0: I need arguments"
                        return 1
                fi
                while getopts "anpPkKde" opt
                do
                        case "$opt" in
                                (a) autol=yes  ;;
                                (n) new=yes  ;;
                                ([pPkK]) if [[ -n "$type" ]]
                                        then
                                                print -u2 "$0: type already set to $type"
                                                return 1
                                        fi
                                        if [[ "$opt" = p ]]
                                        then
                                                type=pattern
                                        elif [[ "$opt" = P ]]
                                        then
                                                type=postpattern
                                        elif [[ "$opt" = K ]]
                                        then
                                                type=widgetkey
                                        else
                                                type=key
                                        fi ;;
                                (d) delete=yes  ;;
                                (e) eval=yes  ;;
                        esac
                done
                shift OPTIND-1
                if (( ! $# ))
                then
                        print -u2 "$0: I need arguments"
                        return 1
                fi
                if [[ -z "$delete" ]]
                then
                        if [[ -z "$eval" ]] && [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                        then
                                while (( $# ))
                                do
                                        if [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                                        then
                                                cmd="${1%%\=*}"
                                                svc="${1#*\=}"
                                                func="$_comps[${_services[(r)$svc]:-$svc}]"
                                                [[ -n ${_services[$svc]} ]] && svc=${_services[$svc]}
                                                [[ -z "$func" ]] && func="${${_patcomps[(K)$svc][1]}:-${_postpatcomps[(K)$svc][1]}}"
                                                if [[ -n "$func" ]]
                                                then
                                                        _comps[$cmd]="$func"
                                                        _services[$cmd]="$svc"
                                                else
                                                        print -u2 "$0: unknown command or service: $svc"
                                                        ret=1
                                                fi
                                        else
                                                print -u2 "$0: invalid argument: $1"
                                                ret=1
                                        fi
                                        shift
                                done
                                return ret
                        fi
                        func="$1"
                        [[ -n "$autol" ]] && autoload -Uz "$func"
                        shift
                        case "$type" in
                                (widgetkey) while [[ -n $1 ]]
                                        do
                                                if [[ $# -lt 3 ]]
                                                then
                                                        print -u2 "$0: compdef -K requires <widget> <comp-widget> <key>"
                                                        return 1
                                                fi
                                                [[ $1 = _* ]] || 1="_$1"
                                                [[ $2 = .* ]] || 2=".$2"
                                                [[ $2 = .menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                                                zle -C "$1" "$2" "$func"
                                                if [[ -n $new ]]
                                                then
                                                        bindkey "$3" | IFS=$' \t' read -A opt
                                                        [[ $opt[-1] = undefined-key ]] && bindkey "$3" "$1"
                                                else
                                                        bindkey "$3" "$1"
                                                fi
                                                shift 3
                                        done ;;
                                (key) if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]
                                        then
                                                print -u2 "$0: missing keys"
                                                return 1
                                        fi
                                        if [[ $1 = .* ]]
                                        then
                                                [[ $1 = .menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                                                zle -C "$func" "$1" "$func"
                                        else
                                                [[ $1 = menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                                                zle -C "$func" ".$1" "$func"
                                        fi
                                        shift
                                        for i
                                        do
                                                if [[ -n $new ]]
                                                then
                                                        bindkey "$i" | IFS=$' \t' read -A opt
                                                        [[ $opt[-1] = undefined-key ]] || continue
                                                fi
                                                bindkey "$i" "$func"
                                        done ;;
                                (*) while (( $# ))
                                        do
                                                if [[ "$1" = -N ]]
                                                then
                                                        type=normal
                                                elif [[ "$1" = -p ]]
                                                then
                                                        type=pattern
                                                elif [[ "$1" = -P ]]
                                                then
                                                        type=postpattern
                                                else
                                                        case "$type" in
                                                                (pattern) if [[ $1 = (#b)(*)=(*) ]]
                                                                        then
                                                                                _patcomps[$match[1]]="=$match[2]=$func"
                                                                        else
                                                                                _patcomps[$1]="$func"
                                                                        fi ;;
                                                                (postpattern) if [[ $1 = (#b)(*)=(*) ]]
                                                                        then
                                                                                _postpatcomps[$match[1]]="=$match[2]=$func"
                                                                        else
                                                                                _postpatcomps[$1]="$func"
                                                                        fi ;;
                                                                (*) if [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                                                                        then
                                                                                cmd="${1%%\=*}"
                                                                                svc=yes
                                                                        else
                                                                                cmd="$1"
                                                                                svc=
                                                                        fi
                                                                        if [[ -z "$new" || -z "${_comps[$1]}" ]]
                                                                        then
                                                                                _comps[$cmd]="$func"
                                                                                [[ -n "$svc" ]] && _services[$cmd]="${1#*\=}"
                                                                        fi ;;
                                                        esac
                                                fi
                                                shift
                                        done ;;
                        esac
                else
                        case "$type" in
                                (pattern) unset "_patcomps[$^@]" ;;
                                (postpattern) unset "_postpatcomps[$^@]" ;;
                                (key) print -u2 "$0: cannot restore key bindings"
                                        return 1 ;;
                                (*) unset "_comps[$^@]" ;;
                        esac
                fi
        }
        typeset _i_wdirs _i_wfiles
        _i_wdirs=()
        _i_wfiles=()
        autoload -Uz compaudit
        if [[ -n "$_i_check" ]]
        then
                typeset _i_q
                if ! eval compaudit
                then
                        if [[ -n "$_i_q" ]]
                        then
                                if [[ "$_i_fail" = ask ]]
                                then
                                        if ! read -q "?zsh compinit: insecure $_i_q, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure $_i_q and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? "
                                        then
                                                print -u2 "$0: initialization aborted"
                                                unfunction compinit compdef
                                                unset _comp_dumpfile _comp_secure compprefuncs comppostfuncs _comps _patcomps _postpatcomps _compautos _lastcomp
                                                return 1
                                        fi
                                        _i_wfiles=()
                                        _i_wdirs=()
                                else
                                        (( $#_i_wfiles )) && _i_files=("${(@)_i_files:#(${(j:|:)_i_wfiles%.zwc})}")
                                        (( $#_i_wdirs )) && _i_files=("${(@)_i_files:#(${(j:|:)_i_wdirs%.zwc})/*}")
                                fi
                        fi
                        typeset -g _comp_secure=yes
                fi
        fi
        autoload -Uz compdump compinstall
        _i_done=''
        if [[ -f "$_comp_dumpfile" ]]
        then
                if [[ -n "$_i_check" ]]
                then
                        IFS=$' \t' read -rA _i_line < "$_comp_dumpfile"
                        if [[ _i_autodump -eq 1 && $_i_line[2] -eq $#_i_files && $ZSH_VERSION = $_i_line[4] ]]
                        then
                                builtin . "$_comp_dumpfile"
                                _i_done=yes
                        fi
                else
                        builtin . "$_comp_dumpfile"
                        _i_done=yes
                fi
        fi
        if [[ -z "$_i_done" ]]
        then
                typeset -A _i_test
                for _i_dir in $fpath
                do
                        [[ $_i_dir = . ]] && continue
                        (( $_i_wdirs[(I)$_i_dir] )) && continue
                        for _i_file in $_i_dir/^([^_]*|*~|*.zwc)(N)
                        do
                                _i_name="${_i_file:t}"
                                (( $+_i_test[$_i_name] + $_i_wfiles[(I)$_i_file] )) && continue
                                _i_test[$_i_name]=yes
                                IFS=$' \t' read -rA _i_line < $_i_file
                                _i_tag=$_i_line[1]
                                shift _i_line
                                case $_i_tag in
                                        (\#compdef) if [[ $_i_line[1] = -[pPkK](n|) ]]
                                                then
                                                        compdef ${_i_line[1]}na "${_i_name}" "${(@)_i_line[2,-1]}"
                                                else
                                                        compdef -na "${_i_name}" "${_i_line[@]}"
                                                fi ;;
                                        (\#autoload) autoload -Uz "$_i_line[@]" ${_i_name}
                                                [[ "$_i_line" != \ # ]] && _compautos[${_i_name}]="$_i_line"  ;;
                                esac
                        done
                done
                if [[ $_i_autodump = 1 ]]
                then
                        compdump
                fi
        fi
        for _i_line in complete-word delete-char-or-list expand-or-complete expand-or-complete-prefix list-choices menu-complete menu-expand-or-complete reverse-menu-complete
        do
                zle -C $_i_line .$_i_line _main_complete
        done
        zle -la menu-select && zle -C menu-select .menu-select _main_complete
        bindkey '^i' | IFS=$' \t' read -A _i_line
        if [[ ${_i_line[2]} = expand-or-complete ]] && zstyle -a ':completion:' completer _i_line && (( ${_i_line[(i)_expand]} <= ${#_i_line} ))
        then
                bindkey '^i' complete-word
        fi
        unfunction compinit compaudit
        autoload -Uz compinit compaudit
        return 0
}
compinstall () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XUz
}
down-line-or-beginning-search () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XU
}
edit-command-line () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XU
}
is-at-least () {
        emulate -L zsh
        local IFS=".-" min_cnt=0 ver_cnt=0 part min_ver version order
        min_ver=(${=1})
        version=(${=2:-$ZSH_VERSION} 0)
        while (( $min_cnt <= ${#min_ver} ))
        do
                while [[ "$part" != <-> ]]
                do
                        (( ++ver_cnt > ${#version} )) && return 0
                        if [[ ${version[ver_cnt]} = *[0-9][^0-9]* ]]
                        then
                                order=(${version[ver_cnt]} ${min_ver[ver_cnt]})
                                if [[ ${version[ver_cnt]} = <->* ]]
                                then
                                        [[ $order != ${${(On)order}} ]] && return 1
                                else
                                        [[ $order != ${${(O)order}} ]] && return 1
                                fi
                                [[ $order[1] != $order[2] ]] && return 0
                        fi
                        part=${version[ver_cnt]##*[^0-9]}
                done
                while true
                do
                        (( ++min_cnt > ${#min_ver} )) && return 0
                        [[ ${min_ver[min_cnt]} = <-> ]] && break
                done
                (( part > min_ver[min_cnt] )) && return 0
                (( part < min_ver[min_cnt] )) && return 1
                part=''
        done
}
up-line-or-beginning-search () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XU
}
url-quote-magic () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XUz
}
```

It seems some kind of script is written to stdout, instead of executed. However, I cannot find what the problem is. It might have something to do with completion, as the completion is not working.
Does anyone has any suggestion what the problem might be or  where I should look next?

Comment: Have the same issue but only when I execute `sudo -s`. Did you find out why does that happen?

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue.
Re-installing Homebrew fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the default shell to zsh.

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```